# Get paragraph items within only the selected table cells

Tags: office-js, office365api, word-addins, office365connectors

I am working on an add-in for Word using Office JS. I have an issue getting the current selected paragraphs items within a Table selection, with a subset of table cells selected. The API only returns the paragraph items of the last selected Table Row.

I would like to get only the specific paragraphs within the currently selected cells:

[image]

The problem is that always only receive the last row of the selection:
[image]

The code is so simple but I have not idea about what I am doing wrong:

```
export async function getSelection() {
   await window.Word.run(async (context) => {
      const range = context.document.getSelection()
      const paragraphs = range.paragraphs
    
      range.load(['paragraphs'])
      paragraphs.load()
    
      await context.sync()
    
      console.log('Paragraphs', paragraphs.items)
   })
}
```

I am trying to use TableCellCollection but I have not idea about how get them. Could anyone help me?
Link to the documentation about TableCellCollection:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.tablecellcollection?view=word-js-preview

Comment: I suspect Word thinks you have multiple, discontinuous ranges. Let's try a few experiments: What happens if you select ALL the cells from the 6 to the 19? What happens if you select all the cells in the table? What happens if you select the paragraph above the table, and the table, and the paragraph below the table>

Answer (score 0):

For Rick:
If you select entire rows (including the final row character) then getSelection returns all selected cells:
[image]
[image]

If you do the same but it selecting only the cells then the bug appears again:
[image]
[image]